# Raspberry Pi 4 Compatibility with OSMC

Tags: osmc

An rPi4 was sent as a gift: will it work with an existing OSMC SD card that is known to work with an rPi3 B+?

Comment: how old is the version of OSMC on the sd-card? does OSMC even support rpi4 yet (last I read, the answer to that was no) - the OSMC site is where you can find the answer to your problem

Comment: Any SDCard created before July 2019 won't boot on a RPi 4. Get LibreElec that's fully supported on RPi4 https://libreelec.tv/raspberry-pi-4/